# Is it possible to modify browser page DOM using classic C code injection, without writing an extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, code-injection, malware

On my local home computer, I want to be able to change my **Chrome web browser** page content dynamically, **without using google extension API.**

For example, when I surf here on `Stackoverflow.com`, I want to be able to replace every picture on the web page, with a picture of mine. Or alternatively, add a `<script> ... code ... </script>` to the web page and execute it. Also, I want it to be done automatically \ periodically from a remote compiled program without using `chrome extensions`

I know this is possible (or has been possible, up to latest chrome versions), as Google is now trying to block completely 3rd party applications from injecting code into their browser:
https://blog.chromium.org/2017/11/reducing-chrome-crashes-caused-by-third.html

Regardless of that, or future limitations, how did the 3rd party applications code injection work to change or read the web interface?
This is also called [man-in-the-browser or MITB and as mentioned in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-browser), no banking malware today is capable of injecting code to chrome, but to any other browser, it seems possible. Whats the difference between chrome and all other browsers which made it possible?

Things I **want**:

- Research directions, or places to start looking for an answer
- If I could get some C \ C++ \ Python examples of doing something like that, it would be great!

Things I **dont want**:

- Examples of extensions which i could use only if loaded from within the web page beforehand
- Man-In-The-Middle solution
- Using a Proxy
- Any network based solution which requires me to have control over GW, routing etc

What im trying to achieve: is finding out whether i can detect such changes from a javascript context, if it affects the browser in a detectable manner somehow. Even if it is on an older version of Chrome, it is still relevant.

Comment: *"What im trying to achieve: is finding out whether i can detect such changes from a javascript context, if it affects the browser in a detectable manner somehow."* Can you elaborate on that, please? Also, given that Chrome 68 will close this window, why try to start using it now?

Comment: Hey, @T.J.Crowder, Even when or if google will try to block these injection methods completely, it is still relevant on **older** chrome versions, so (A) theoretically it will still be possible to downgrade chrome version by malicious code. (B) If bad actors will find a way to bypass these defensive techniques, the outcome should be quite similar - change the web interface, one way or another. I still want to see how this is done, and if it can be detected somehow. I hope i made it a bit more clear?